# Coloring every segment of polyline with different color in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am looking for a way to draw every segment of polyline (or path if it is easier) with different color (first line blue conected to red etc. but in one polyline). Alternatively is there a way to treat every vertex on polyline as shape, set it different color, making smooth transition of color between them?

Edit: Multiple lines in one container is not good enough for me unless there exist a way to connect them visually with methods like strokeLineJoin. I just don't get why it is impossible to treat every segment of polyline/path as a shape and set it with different color, it seems like so natural thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want sir - this is how it looks

[image]

```
package application;

import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.HLineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      try {
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),
                getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),
                 getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),
                getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30),getLine(10,30));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Node getLine(int ponts,int pontLength){
    HBox root = new HBox(-1);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Random r = new Random();
    while(ponts !=0){
        Path p1 = new Path();
        p1.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(), new HLineTo(pontLength));
        p1.setStroke(Color.rgb(r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255)));
        root.getChildren().add(p1);
        ponts--;
    }

    return root;
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.stop();
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code, instead of a screenshot of the code? For one thing, you can't copy and paste from a screenshot, and for another, the screenshot is not complete.

Comment: i thought i linked the code that is why i did not post it, now i have thanks for the notice sir.@James_D

Comment: That is just multiple lines in one container it is not good enough for me. I want these lines to be connected by same methods like segments in polyline and to be able to use strokeLineJoin on them. I just don't get why it is impossible for me to treat every line as single shape and set it with different color in polyline, it seems so natural thing to do.